# How can access to My AWS account's console and API be limited to connections from my VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I want to limit access to my AWS account to my VPN. I see the option of using sourceIP for IP whitelisting, alowing my proxy's and AWS IPs.

Is there a way to do limit the calls to AWS API to VPN as well? I am not looking for VPC endpoint blocking.

Comment: One option I can think of is to create a EC2 instance with an elastic IP, connect to this VM over VPN and allow service access from this elastic IP only. But doesn't that service call from EC2 to AWS API goes through internet again? I can get a waiver on console access for the routine tasks.

Comment: On second thought, that would need non-scaling Build servers in multiple AZ acting as bastion hosts. It already sounds ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the iam policies for your users to add a [`condition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html) that only allows if the `SourceIp` matches your proxy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*,
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress" : {
          "aws:SourceIp" : ["192.0.2.0/24"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Set the `aws:SourceIp` as the IP your VPN has you connecting from

Comment: Limiting IP to my proxy (not VPN) will not tunnel my communication to AWS API. Yes, SourceIp is my fallback option.

Comment: @user6317694 the console is always accessed via the Internet... and you will find that even this answer isn't going to work for all cases, because sometimes the interaction is console > service 1 > service 2, such as when EC2 calls KMS when starting instances with encrypted volumes.  Service 1 won't be using your source address, and the request will fail with source-ip blocking.